# how is timer variable executed and Fired logged to console?

Tags: javascript

```
var fireCount =0;
var start = new Date
var timer=setInterval(function () {
    if(new Date - start > 1000){
        clearInterval(timer)
        console.log('Fired ',fireCount)
    }
    fireCount++;
},0)
```

> Result: Fired 770
>
> What I expected: Blank or no output

trying to understand callbacks and see this example on the way...can someone explain when timer gets called and how is 'Fired' logged to console?

is timer an IFFE (immediately invoked function expression) here?

am i missing something here?
how is setInterval executing?

what is the difference between the below two function variables?

```
var timer=setInterval(function () {
    if(new Date - start > 1000){
        clearInterval(timer)
        console.log('Fired ',fireCount)
    }
    fireCount++;
},0)


var x=function () {
    console.log('x')
}
```

how does timer get printed while x does not?

well, i experimented a little more, and found,

```
var x=setInterval(function () {
    console.log('x')
})
```

prints x to console indefinitely as expected....

so is it because the callback waited to see no code exists in the event queue and hence executed the callback?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is function witch gets `function` and `number` (representing ms) this function is then executed evry `n` ms.

the return value of `setInterval` function allows canceling this 'loop' using function `clearInterval`

Comment: sure i get that but when does it get called? isnt the function definition just assigned to timer variable?

we havent called timer "as of yet" but still , my console gets logged with 'Fired 770'

i would like to know when is it being called?

Comment: it's called evry time after interval is set after timeout you specified

Answer (score 0):

if the interval parameter of setInterval function is less than 10, 10ms will be set by default.

In your case each 10ms your function is exectuted, and only that 770th times your condition was true so you can see the log in console,
 the timer is killed with clearInterval so the function will be not invoke anymore

Answer (score 0):

from the w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

---

Maybe it's more clear at the beginning to see it in this form:

```
var timer = setInterval(functToEvalueate(){..}, interval)
```

Because you passed 0 as interval, you're timer evaluates the first argument every millisecond until the below expression is true:

```
new Date - start > 1000
```

Comment: have updated my question...can you please check it?

why is it getting logged?
we have not called timer explicitly to invoke the `setInterval` function in the first place?

Comment: You're confusing assignment over evaluating.

this is a simple and only assignment, where timer store the function and calling timer() you evaluate the code
`var timer = function add(x,y) { ... }`

Or you assign to timer the executed, that's your case
`var timer =add(1,2) //<- can you see i'm executing the function?`